# How to use HashAlgorithm.TransformBlock / TransformFinalBlock?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha

I want to compute an SHA1 hash in several steps using `TransformBlock()`/`TransformFinalBlock()` :

```
byte[] block1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("This");
byte[] block2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("is");
byte[] block3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Sparta");

SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
sha.TransformBlock(block1, 0, block1.Length, block1, 0);
sha.TransformBlock(block2, 0, block2.Length, block2, 0);
sha.TransformFinalBlock(block3, 0, block3.Length);

byte[] result = sha.Hash;
```

I know there is other ways to compute SHA1 (eg : `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash()` or `CryptoStream`). What is above is a simplified version of more complex code.

**What is totally unclear to me is what to pass for the *outputBuffer array* (the fourth parameter of TransformBlock method)**  :

```
int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, 
                   byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset);
```

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock(v=vs.110).aspx) says :

> Computes the hash value for the specified region of the input byte
>   array and **copies the specified region of the input byte array to the
>   specified region of the output byte array**

What if I don't need that array copy ? Should I pass `null` ? (to avoid input array to be copied each time ?)

Is there a typical use of this ?

Similarly, it seems TransformFinalBlock() also copied input array to an output array. AFAIKm this is what is returned by the method :

```
byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount);
```

Comment: Personally I don't think this interface is all that good a match for a hash function. Actually, I think it is a horrible design anyway because a block is something that *has been explicitly specified internally* for block ciphers  and hashes. In that definition, `"This"` is **not** a block. However, instead of offering a low level interface it offers a high level interface that doesn't do what you would expect, confusing the casual reader. **I'd rather use the streaming interface instead.** The original designer should hide in shame for this interface definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page and the example you linked are quite clear:

> Calling the TransformBlock method with different input and output arrays results in an IOException.

and even the example is clear on the use:

```
offset += sha.TransformBlock(input, offset, size, input, offset);
```

`SHA1` doesn't really need that parameter. But it is an implementation of the interface `ICryptoTransform` that has this signature. So `SHA1.TransformBlock()` has that (useless) parameter. Note that you can set output to `null` (undocumented but works).

Note that in the `HashAlgorithm` (that is the base class of `SHA1` that implements `ICryptoTransform`), inside the `TransformBlock` there is a [line](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/hashalgorithm.cs,151) like:

```
if ((outputBuffer != null) && ((inputBuffer != outputBuffer) || (inputOffset != outputOffset)))
    Buffer.BlockCopy(inputBuffer, inputOffset, outputBuffer, outputOffset, inputCount);
```

So if you set it to `null` or to `input == output` then nothing will be copied.

Comment: Seems passing null is also perfectly valid (at least for SHA1 and MD5 implementations) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623159/i-have-the-wrong-hash-values-c-sharp-cryptography#answer-623211

Comment: In my opinion, it is a horrible design decision of the .NET team. Clearly they had this idea that *because* of the already incorrect `ICryptoTransform` design (again conflating input and output) they had to do *something* with the `outputBuffer`. However, copying input can lead to leakage of information. And since a hash function doesn't change the input anyway, then why would you copy it? It fails clean design principles: 1. doing two things at once and more importantly 2. the least surprise principle. Use the streaming interface, at least it doesn't require you to handle non-existing output.